# How can a Chrome Packaged App interact with a webview (listen to events fired from it)

Tags: webview, google-chrome-app

Is it possible for a Chrome Packaged App to listen to events fired by a webview inside the ChromeApp?

My ChromeApp loads a webview on startup. I would like to be able to fire events from the webview so I can access local chrome.app functions.

The function I would like to use now is "close window" (so I can close the ChromeApp from the webview that is inside the ChromeApp). In the future I would like to be able to access the Storage API from the webview.

Comment: What exactly events did you have in mind? Would any of the [standard DOM events that <webview> supports](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview.html#dom_events) work for you?

Comment: Thanks!, that's probably the solution to my "close window" problem. Also I would like to be able to access the Storage API from the webview. Do you have any idea how I can achieve this? (I've updated my question)

Comment: Ok, clear now! I'll enter a proper answer in the main section below then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<webview>` supports a [restricted set of standard DOM events](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview.html#dom_events) out of the box. For your "close window" interception, the aptly named [`close event`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview.html#event-close) is probably the best fit.

If you want to establish a kind of communication channel between a webview guest and your app in the general case, as in your second use case with accessing Storage API, you have a couple of options:

- You can use [`<webview>.contentWindow.postMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview.html#method-ContentWindow-postMessage) to post messages into the guest page and return replies in the reverse direction.
- You can also inject pieces of JavaScript into your webview guest using [`<webview>.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview.html#method-executeScript). This way you can, for example, attach a click event handler to a button within the guest that will do something that you need to do in the execution context of your app (of course, for that your event handler has to be a closure). Or, you can gather some information from within the guest and return in to the app in the `executeScript`'s callback.
- Finally, there is [`<webview>.insertCSS`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview.html#method-insertCSS) - not a fit for your needs, but I'm mentioning it to complete the set of methods you can use to interact with or alter the webview guest.